# Timeouts when connecting to SQL Server since installing SP1 for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, timeout

I just installed SP1 for windows 7 and I have severe performance degradation when connecting to SQL Server 2005 since then. Establishing connection takes more than 30 seconds while it's instantaneous on another computer. Firewall is disabled and I didn't make any change to the configuration.

What can cause such a problem?

Thankds in advance!

Comment: Try to check for any dns settings and use ip instead of name

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, run the following in an elevated Command Prompt:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

Hopefully this is not too late to help.

<sub>This is not my answer, it comes from [Smiley1244 from the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ae849959-b31f-4984-b54f-45dd38fdddf7/) but it is THE answer.</sub>

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide a link for future reference!